# Erro com funções de nomeação de variáveis em uma lista

Tags: r

Tento executar uma função para renomear variáveis de `data.frame`s de uma `list` e obtenho apenas mensagens de erro.

Quando executo a função para um banco de dados a análise ocorre:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble=structure(list(var1 = c(28.5627505742013, 22.8311421908438, 95.2216156944633, 
43.9405107684433, 97.11211245507, 48.4108281508088), var2 = c(32.9009465128183, 
54.1136392951012, 69.3181485682726, 70.2100433968008, 44.0986660309136, 
62.8759404085577), var3 = c(89.6971945464611, 67.174579706043, 
37.0924087055027, 87.7977314218879, 29.3221596442163, 37.5143952667713
), var4 = c(41.5336912125349, 98.2095112837851, 80.7970978319645, 
91.1278881691396, 66.4086666144431, 69.2618868127465), var5 = c(33.9312525652349, 
88.1815139763057, 98.4453701227903, 25.0217059068382, 41.1195872165263, 
37.0983888953924), var6 = c(39.813664201647, 80.6405956856906, 
30.0273275375366, 34.6203793399036, 96.5195455029607, 44.5830867439508
), kmeans = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = 
c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "kmeans", "group"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Função:

```
names(tibble)[str_which(names(tibble),regex('KMEaNS',ignore_case=TRUE))]<-'variable'
```

No caso de uma `list`, o resultado não é retornado:

```
mylist=structure(list(dataset1 = structure(list(var1 = c(28.5627505742013, 
22.8311421908438, 95.2216156944633, 43.9405107684433, 97.11211245507, 
48.4108281508088), var2 = c(32.9009465128183, 54.1136392951012, 
69.3181485682726, 70.2100433968008, 44.0986660309136, 62.8759404085577
), var3 = c(89.6971945464611, 67.174579706043, 37.0924087055027, 
87.7977314218879, 29.3221596442163, 37.5143952667713), var4 = c(41.5336912125349, 
98.2095112837851, 80.7970978319645, 91.1278881691396, 66.4086666144431, 
69.2618868127465), var5 = c(33.9312525652349, 88.1815139763057, 
98.4453701227903, 25.0217059068382, 41.1195872165263, 37.0983888953924
), var6 = c(39.813664201647, 80.6405956856906, 30.0273275375366, 
34.6203793399036, 96.5195455029607, 44.5830867439508), kmeans = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", "var2", 
"var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "kmeans", "group"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), dataset2 = structure(list(
var1 = c(28.5627505742013, 22.8311421908438, 95.2216156944633, 
43.9405107684433, 97.11211245507, 48.4108281508088), var2 = c(32.9009465128183, 
54.1136392951012, 69.3181485682726, 70.2100433968008, 44.0986660309136, 
62.8759404085577), var3 = c(89.6971945464611, 67.174579706043, 
37.0924087055027, 87.7977314218879, 29.3221596442163, 37.5143952667713
), var4 = c(41.5336912125349, 98.2095112837851, 80.7970978319645, 
91.1278881691396, 66.4086666144431, 69.2618868127465), var5 = c(33.9312525652349, 
88.1815139763057, 98.4453701227903, 25.0217059068382, 41.1195872165263, 
37.0983888953924), var6 = c(39.813664201647, 80.6405956856906, 
30.0273275375366, 34.6203793399036, 96.5195455029607, 44.5830867439508
), kmeans = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = 
c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "kmeans", "group"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), dataset3 = structure(list(
var1 = c(28.5627505742013, 22.8311421908438, 95.2216156944633, 
43.9405107684433, 97.11211245507, 48.4108281508088), var2 = c(32.9009465128183, 
54.1136392951012, 69.3181485682726, 70.2100433968008, 44.0986660309136, 
62.8759404085577), var3 = c(89.6971945464611, 67.174579706043, 
37.0924087055027, 87.7977314218879, 29.3221596442163, 37.5143952667713
), var4 = c(41.5336912125349, 98.2095112837851, 80.7970978319645, 
91.1278881691396, 66.4086666144431, 69.2618868127465), var5 = c(33.9312525652349, 
88.1815139763057, 98.4453701227903, 25.0217059068382, 41.1195872165263, 
37.0983888953924), var6 = c(39.813664201647, 80.6405956856906, 
30.0273275375366, 34.6203793399036, 96.5195455029607, 44.5830867439508
), kmeans = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = 
c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "kmeans", "group"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), .Names = c("dataset1", 
"dataset2", "dataset3"))
```

Função 1:

```
mylist%>%
  lapply(function(x){
    lapply(x,names(x)[str_which(names(x),regex('KMEa',ignore_case=T))])<-'variable'
  })
```

> Error in lapply(x, names(x)[str_which(names(x), regex("KMEa", ignore_case = T))]) <- "variable" : 
>     could not find function "lapply<-"

Função 2:

```
mylist%>%
  map(.,~names(.)[str_which(names(.),regex('KM',ignore_case=T))])<-'variable'
```

> Error in mylist %>% map(., ~names(.)[str_which(names(.), regex("KM", ignore_case = T))]) <- "variable" : 
>     could not find function "%>%<-"

**Duas perguntas:**

- quais os erros nos dois códigos?
- há alguma solução semelhante com o `dplyr::rename`?

Comment: você pode dar uma simplificadazinha em `stringr::str_replace_all(...)` no argumento `pattern` sem precisar usar `stringr::regex()` por causa do argumento `ignore_case = T`. Basta usar o caracter especial "(?i)" em`pattern` o que denota ignorar se o caractére é maiúsculo ou minúsculo (ver minha resposta).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que nem a função `lapply` nem a função `map` permitem modificações *in-place*  dos objetos.

Quando você usa o operador de atribuição `<-` no lado direito de um lapply ele não sabe o que fazer com aquilo.

No seu caso eu acho que faria algo assim:

```
mylist %>% 
  map(~set_names(
    .x, 
    nm = str_replace_all(
      names(.x), 
      pattern = regex("KM.*", ignore_case = TRUE),
      "variable"
      )
    )
  )
```

De qualquer forma, quando as funções anônimas começam a ficar mais complicadas, é interessante separá-las em outras funções para deixar o código mais legível. Por exemplo:

```
renomear_df <- function(df) {
  names(df)[str_which(names(df),regex('KMEaNS',ignore_case=TRUE))]<-'variable'
  df
}

mylist %>% map(renomear_df)
```

A idéia dos `maps` é essa mesmo. Você cria uma função que funciona para uma peça isoladamente e com um comando faz ela funcionar para uma lista de peças.
Quando a função que você usa para transformar a peça é simples você pode usar uma função anônima ou as fórmulas do `purrr`, quando ela é mais complexa o ideal é separá-la numa função auxiliar, o que deixa o código muito mais legível.

Não existe nenhuma solução bonita com `rename` pq ele precisa do nome exato da variável e não deixa você fazer seleções por regex.

Comment: Uma dúvida: por que usa-se o elemento  de `function(x)` (que é `df`, neste caso) ao final de algumas funções?

Comment: por que `names(df) <- "alguma coisa"` não retorna nada ( na verdade, ele retorna invisivelmente os nomes das colunas), e o que vc quer que a função retorne é o data.frame com os nomes modificados.

Comment: vc pode ver mais aqui: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#modify-in-place ou aqui https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#attributes

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução com `dplyr` seria:

```
library(dplyr)

map(mylist,~rename_at(.,vars(contains('EaN')),~'variable'))
```

`contains` tem ação semelhante a `stringr::regex` com `ignore_case=TRUE`

Retirado (e adaptado) [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138648/error-with-rename-functions-into-a-list-on-r/54138913#54138913).

Answer (score 3):

As respostas dadas são excelentes e obedecem ao padrão `tidyverse`. De qualquer modo, darei outras soluções usando o excelente pacote `data.table` e `base`.

### Solução data.table

`data.table` tem a função `data.table::setnames()` que renomeia variáveis de data frames sem a necessidade de apontar para objetos. O processo é feito por referência, sem fazer nenhuma cópia adicional durante o processo que a função é chamada. Geralmente para fazer operações com `data.table`, você precisa transformar o objeto em `data.table`. Porém, para renomear variáveis, `data.table::setnames()` funciona com `tibble` e classe é preservada. A solução é bem simples e executa com `lapply()`:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x){
  ind <- grep(x = names(x), pattern = "(?i)km")
  data.table::setnames(x, names(x)[[ind]], "variable")
})
```

Resultado (parcial):

```
> head(mylist[[1]])
# A tibble: 6 x 8
   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 variable group
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <fct>
1  28.6  32.9  89.7  41.5  33.9  39.8 2        a    
2  22.8  54.1  67.2  98.2  88.2  80.6 1        a    
3  95.2  69.3  37.1  80.8  98.4  30.0 3        a    
4  43.9  70.2  87.8  91.1  25.0  34.6 1        a    
5  97.1  44.1  29.3  66.4  41.1  96.5 3        a    
6  48.4  62.9  37.5  69.3  37.1  44.6 1        a
```

### Solução base R

```
# re-execute o código original para restaurar 'mylist'
for(i in seq_along(mylist)){
  ind <- grep(x = names(mylist[[i]]), pattern = "(?i)km")
  names(mylist[[i]])[[ind]] <- "variable"
}
rm(i)
```

Aqui usamos um `for()` loop. Resultado:

```
> head(mylist[[1]])
# A tibble: 6 x 8
   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 variable group
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <fct>
1  28.6  32.9  89.7  41.5  33.9  39.8 2        a    
2  22.8  54.1  67.2  98.2  88.2  80.6 1        a    
3  95.2  69.3  37.1  80.8  98.4  30.0 3        a    
4  43.9  70.2  87.8  91.1  25.0  34.6 1        a    
5  97.1  44.1  29.3  66.4  41.1  96.5 3        a    
6  48.4  62.9  37.5  69.3  37.1  44.6 1        a
```